# which dependencies to add mitigating from spring cloud sleuth to micrometer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, micrometer

so as spring cloud sleuth is discontinued for spring boot 3.0 im shifiting to micrometer. i read about two dependencies to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

i used slueth auto configuration to add all trace and span ids in the logs of all services, propagating the ids in the headers of calls via feign and adding them to logs. Also i used tracer to get current trace id for custom logs.

Now which of these dependency do i need to add for spring to autoconfigure these 2 things that i need? (tracer and adding trace and span ids to logs and headers of downstream services) and also if im missing anything.
Edit: already added these 2 config properties

```
#to trace all calls (micrometer only does 10% of calls by default)
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
#to add trace and span id in all calls (isnt done by default)
logging.pattern.level= "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the Brave bridge and actuator.
If you are using Boot 3.2 or higher `logging.pattern.level` is not needed.